# Как скрыть div при нажатии outside?

Tags: javascript

Div при клике на который показываем second div:

```html
<div class="first pull-right h-btn" data-ng-if="user"
data-ng-click="viewModel.showLogout = !viewModel.showLogout">

<div class="second"  data-ng-if="viewModel.showLogout" data-ng-click="logout()">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Log out</a>
                </div>
```

Как при нажатии outside скрыть div с class="second"?

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно так:

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $(".second");

  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    container.hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first pull-right h-btn" data-ng-if="user" data-ng-click="viewModel.showLogout = !viewModel.showLogout">
  <div class="second" data-ng-if="viewModel.showLogout" data-ng-click="logout()">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Log out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[ДЕМО](http://jsfiddle.net/94ujjhtk/)